# PHP UTC Timestamp Creation

Tags: php

I am using ubuntu(apache) for my php application.i need to create a timestamp for authenticated call of a webservice.In php i getting only 10 digit timestamp like 1273229733.But i need to create like 1273229613000 .How can i solve this problem.help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The thirteen-digit timestamp is the number of milliseconds (1/1,000) since the Unix epoch (compared to the ten-digit *seconds* since). PHP has a function to return the timestamp to the microsecond (1/1,000,000) which we can multiply and truncate to get our thirteen-digit timestamp.

```
$millitimestamp = floor(microtime(TRUE) * 1000);
```

Comment: thank you for your response.sorry to inform you that now it returns only eleven digit timestamp.This is not what i looking for...sorry